# Jquery results are inconsistent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have (2) jquery autocomplete controls back-to-back. When I enter and select a value in the first box, and then enter and select a value in the second box, everything is going well. If I then go back to the first text box and enter in a value, I will get the error message from the second autocomplete control.

Any ideas?
This is the first text box

```
        $("#txtCIPCriteria").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                delay: 250,
                url: $('#hdfldPath').val(),
                data: "{ 'Name': '" + request.term.replace(/'/g, "\&apos") + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('|')[0],
                            val: item.split('|')[1]
                            //label: item.Text,
                            //value: item.Value
                        }   // end of return
                    }))   // end of response
                }   // end of success
            });     // end of ajax
        },  // end of source
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#hdfldCIPCode").val(i.item.val);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                    $(event.target).val('');
                }
            },
        minLength: 2
    });     //  end of $("#txtCIPCriteria").autocomplete
```

This is the second control

```
        $("#txtBuildingsCriteria").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                delay: 250,
                url: $('#hdfldPath').val(),
                data: "{ 'Name': '" + request.term.replace(/'/g, "\&apos") + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('|')[0],
                            val: item.split('|')[1]
                            //label: item.Text,
                            //value: item.Value
                        }   // end of return
                    }))    // end of response
                }   // end of success
            });     // end of ajax
        },  // end of source
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#hdfldBuilding").val(i.item.val);
            //                GetFiscalAgents1(i.item.val);
            var CipCode = $('#hdfldCIPCode').val();
            var Bldg = $("#hdfldBuilding").val();
            var ProgType = $('#ddlProgramType').val();

            GetFiscalAgents1(i.item.val);
            GetProspRegion(i.item.val);

            //var Result = FindCIPCodeCount(CipCode, Bldg, ProgType)
            //if (Result == 'Exists') {
            //    MsgBox('This is an active CIPCode, Building and ProgramType combination already. Please change your criteria.');
            //}
            //else {
            //    $("#hdfldBuilding").val(i.item.val);
            //    GetFiscalAgents1(i.item.val);
            //    GetProspRegion(i.item.val);
            //}
        },
         change: function (event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        $(event.target).val('');
                    }
                },
        minLength: 3
    });     //  end of $("#txtBuildingsCriteria").autocomplete
```

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the problem, but you shouldn't try to create your own JSON, use `JSON.stringify()` on an object.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also, in JSON, strings have to be surrounded with double quotes, not single qoutes. So `"{ 'Name': ...}"` is wrong, because `Name` has to be in double quotes.

Comment: I have a custom error in the autocompletes for each textbox result, and this is what will get returned in the first autocomplete, if I go back to it after filling in the second textbox.

Comment: Have you looked in the Network tab of the web console to see what parameter you're sending to the server URL during the second autocomplete.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem you're having? You type something in the first field, but it displays an error in the second field?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `cache: false` inside ajax function